# Bond Risk Premia in Affine Term Structure Models

Tags: term-structure

Can somebody point me to any notes on how to "back out" what's the implied term premium after we have calibrated an affine term structure model?

I was able to calibrate to the yields cov matrix as well as the yield curve (Q-measure). I came across in some book that they were also able to work out the P-measure yield curve,

[image]

so i wonder how the green curve in the figure is obtained from the model.

Comment: From what book is that image?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Bond-Pricing-Yield-Curve-Modeling/dp/1107165857

Comment: Hey @Danny Did you read the rest of the book? I was gonna post some references but I just quickly skimmed the book and it already covers all the techniques you need... Try searching for Kalman filter in the book or the simpler linear regression method in chapter 34.

Comment: @Helin yes i have the book but it’s unclear how they do it